# How to get complete dependency list of kernel modules at runtime

Tags: linux, kernel-module

Is there a way to list down from command line the complete dependency list of kernel modules loaded in the kernel at runtime?

Let me clarify my question a little bit.

What I am  trying to do:

1. I get a list of all loaded modules using `lsmod`
2. Then remove/unload currently loaded kernel modules by running a loop. I am using `modprobe -r`. This step fails (obviously) as some modules are in use.
   (I can switch to using `rmmod -r`, but don't want to as it is unsafe and can crash the system.)
3. Then I want to load the modules one by one again.

It is step 2 that is failing, as I cannot get all the module dependencies before using `modprobe -r`.

Any ideas, suggestions or comments ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However lsmod o/p is sometimes incomplete. It also does not always indicate all the modules dependent on a given module.

What you see in lsmod in the "Used by" column are merely the static symbol dependencies that you can also look at using `modinfo`.

If however a piece of kernel code takes a reference on a module using (try_)module_get, the caller will not be recorded. References do not have an owner (moduleA could pass the pointer to moduleB, which then module_puts it..), there is nothing to record for the Used by column.

Comment: What does it mean if there is `1` in `Used by ` column?

Comment: That works, but of course, it's _reversed_... If A depends on B, you need to `modinfo A`, but B is the module you want to know the dependencies from... That can be annoying on system with a large number of modules.

Answer (score 5):

To get a list of module dependencies as would be used by `modprobe` (i.e. this should normally be the full list, but see the answer by user502515), use

```
$ modprobe --show-depends <module>
```

Note that this command shows more information than `modinfo`'s `depends:` line, as it lists dependencies recursively (i.e. dependencies of dependencies).
It also takes into account `alias` commands in modprobe configuration files.

Tested using:

```
$ modprobe -V
kmod version 14
```

Answer (score 2):

man lsmod: lsmod is a trivial program which nicely formats the contents of the `/proc/modules`, showing what kernel modules are currently loaded.

Edited:
see also: `depmod -n`

Comment: I know about lsmod. However lsmod o/p is sometimes incomplete. It also does not always indicate all the modules dependent on a given module.